# Rails error finding actionmailer template despite email sending correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a rails app running on passenger with a mailer. I have it so the page following the action shows the email content but I get this error:

```
Missing template rfis/mail, application/mail with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :slim, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/var/www/rqm3/app/views" * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.5.1/app/views" * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.0/app/views"
```

despite this, the email does correctly load the template when being sent.  It's only showing it in a view that causes issues.

rfis_controller.rb:

```
  def mail
    @mail_message = RfiMailer.send_rfi(current_user, @rfi).deliver
  end
```

rfi_mailer.rb:

```
class RfiMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from:"testemail@mail.com"
    def send_rfi(user, rfi)

        mail(to:"other@test.com")
    end
end
```

send_rfi.html.erb:

```
test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is due to you are not redirecting anything inside your method "mail" define inside controller

```
 def mail
   @mail_message = RfiMailer.send_rfi(current_user, @rfi).deliver
   redirect_to @user, notice: "Message sent successfully ."
 end
```

you can also define render nothing

Comment: Thanks, sometimes you get so close to something you overlook the simple stuff.